# Socket.io client not recieving messages when using rooms

Tags: node.js, express, sockets

I am using Node with Express and Socket.io. My client is not receiving messages that are sent to rooms.

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.join('test');

    socket.on('join room', async () => {
        console.log(socket.rooms);
        socket.in('test').emit('hello');
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Output:

```
Listening on port 3000
{ iveM_9ZNcCI2h4UuAAAB: 'iveM_9ZNcCI2h4UuAAAB', test: 'test' }
```

Client:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3000")
    socket.emit("join room")

    socket.on("hello", () => {
        console.log("world")
    })
</script>
```

But nothing is logged client side. If I do `socket.emit("hello")` in `join room`, `world` is logged client side.

*Update*: So it turns out `io.to("test").emit("hello");` works. I am going to create another question asking why this is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Documentation:

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

> Join and Leave methods are **asynchronous** and accept a callback
> argument.

This statement will be executed in Asynchronously.

```
socket.join('test', () => console.log(socket.rooms))
```

So below statement will be called first and at that time the socket has not joined the room test so it won't work.

```
socket.in('test').emit('hello');
```

Try this:

```
socket.join('test', () => {
  console.log(socket.rooms);
  socket.in('test').emit('hello');
});
```

This way it will work because emit will be done once the Socket will join the room.

Let me know if you have any questions.

------------EDIT-------------

Check out this cheat sheet:
https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Which suggests using:

```
io.in('test').emit('hello');
// sending to all clients in 'test' room, including sender
```

If you use:

```
socket.in('test').emit('hello');
// sending to all clients in 'test' room except sender
```

So use the first solution.

Comment: I get the same thing, `{ q_LQhWwnLoROSELmAAAB: 'q_LQhWwnLoROSELmAAAB', test: 'test' }` is logged to the Node console, but nothing is logged in the frontend.

Comment: I've just added my entire server code, could you take another look?